# Why are there multiple suicide calls from one address to a contract in the same block?

Tags: contract-invocation, internal-transactions, selfdestruct

There are several contracts whose internal Tx have only suicide calls from the same contract/user address over and over again. What is the need of having multiple calls?

[image]

Comment: For some reason I've also not had contract suicide when I called them.  I've not yet looked into it deeper but something seems a bit of a miss.

Answer (score 1):

SUICIDE opcode uses negative gas because the operation frees up space on the blockchain by clearing all of the contract's data.

This negative gas deducts from the total gas cost of the transaction, so if you're doing some clean-up operations first, SUICIDE can reduce your gas costs.

Probably all contracts must have been cleared the same user, hence you could see such transactions

Comment: From your answer I think you are referring to one user calling multiple contracts, is that right? Just to clarify my question the one user is calling the suicide function of a single contract in a single block many times (365 times to be exact) .